# How to access a XML file in a maven project so it stays available when packaged

Tags: java, maven-2

I currently started working on a maven web-app project that needs to be launched with the jetty:run-exploded goal for development/debugging in eclipse.

Now, I have an XML file which contents I need to access at runtime. My problem is: where to put the file so that the code that does the reading works both in "exploded" and packaged (i.e. in the WAR) mode?

Putting the file in src/main/java (so as to be in the classpath) won't cut it since maven filters out all non-java files on packaging.
When the file is in src/main/resources, one mean would be to figure out the root path of the project (during eclipse development) and look into that directory - but this won't be the case anymore when the project will be packaged.

Of course I could go into writing code that tries to read the file from both locations, but this seems rather cumbersome. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Files in `src/main/resources` are copied to the `target/classes` directory and are available on the class path. Just read them from the class path. As explained in [How do I add resources to my JAR?](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_add_resources_to_my_JAR) from the maven documentation (with a test resource here):

> In a unit test you could use a simple
>   snippet of code like the following to
>   access the resource required for
>   testing:
>
> ```
> ...
>
> // Retrieve resource
> InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test.properties" );
>
> // Do something with the resource
>
> ...
> ```

Answer (score 1):

In such case I put the file under `src/main/resources` directory and use Spring's [ClassPathResource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html). This way the file is accessible in IDE, during Maven build process and in runtime.