# how to create maven property

Tags: maven-2

How can I create maven property with the classpath as part of it ?

Comment: Do you mean "class path", or ... ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643091/how-to-access-a-xml-file-in-a-maven-project-so-it-stays-available-when-packaged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create anything, simply load your file from the classpath (as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643091/how-to-access-a-xml-file-in-a-maven-project-so-it-stays-available-when-packaged/2643111#2643111)):

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/file.txt " );
...
```